# Adding Windows Login and current Date into Database via cshtml form

Tags: database, firefox, razor, asp-classic, webmatrix

Afternoon.

I need help trying to add my *Windows Login* Name and the *Current Date* into my Current Database from a *form* in my *cshtml* file. Please bare in mind im pretty new to this... I've only started understanding HTML.

The Tools Im using:
WebMatrix 3, Firefox

Name of the database is: sweep hazmat library.sdf

Table name is:kl1explosiv

*Heres the code:*

```
{
    var db = Database.Open("sweep hazmat library");

    var ASIN = "";
    var description = "";
    var dateadded = "";
    var addedby = "";

    if(IsPost){

            //read ASIN.
            ASIN = Request["ASIN"];
            if (ASIN.IsEmpty()){
                Validation.Equals("ASIN", "A Article is needed here");
            }
            //read description.
            description = Request["description"];
            if (description.IsEmpty()){
                Validation.Equals("description", "a description is required");
            }
            //figure out how to add date automatically.
            dateadded = Request["DateTime.Now"];

            addedby = ;
            var SQLINSERT =
                "INSERT INTO kl1explosiv (ASIN, description, dateadded){Values (@0, @1, @datetime.now )";
            db.Execute(SQLINSERT, ASIN, description, dateadded, addedby);
            Response.Redirect("~/EntsorgungsTabelle.cshtml");
}

<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Add an Article</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <p><label for="ASIN">Title:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ASIN" value="@Request.Form["ASIN"]" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("ASIN")
                </p>

                <p><label for="description">beschreibung:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="description" value="@description" />
                     @Html.ValidationMessage("description")
                </p>

                <p><input type="datetime-local" name="Dateadded" value="@dateadded" />  
                </p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add an Article" /></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive managed to fix my own issue with thanks to a friend of mine (cheers Brit) for the hints.

Now the Windows Login also adds itself to the database along with the current date:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("sweep hazmat library");


    var asin = "";
    var description = "";
    var dateadded = DateTime.Now;
    var addedby = Environment.UserName;
    var now = DateTime.Now;  


    if(IsPost){

            //read ASIN.
            asin = Request["asin"];
            if (asin.IsEmpty()){
                Validation.Equals("asin", "A Article is needed here");
            }
            //read description.
            description = Request["description"];
            if (description.IsEmpty()){
                Validation.Equals("description", "a short description is needed here");
            }
            //figure out how to add date automatically.
            dateadded = DateTime.Now;
            addedby = Environment.UserName;
            var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO kl1explosiv (asin, description, dateadded, addedby) Values(@0, @1, @2, @3)";
            db.Execute(SQLINSERT, asin, description, dateadded, addedby);
            db.Close();
            Response.Redirect("EntsorgungsTabelle.cshtml");
        }
    }
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<time datetime="@now.ToString("o")" pubdate>@now.ToLongDateString() @now.ToShortTimeString()</time>
@addedby

 <h2>Add a Movie</h2>
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
 <form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie Information</legend>
        <p><label for="ASIN">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ASIN" value="@Request.Form["ASIN"]" />
            @Html.ValidationMessage("ASIN")
        </p>
        <p><label for="description">beschreibung:</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="@description" style="width: 250px; height: 50px;"/>
            @Html.ValidationMessage("description")
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Add an Article" /></p>
    </fieldset>
    </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Now i'm now able to save system date, time and the windows login into my .sdf database via a .cshtml form